# Python 3: How to follow date Evolution

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would line to check if there is continuity between dates in "Begin" and "End" columns in my dataframe, by putting boolean value in a column name "continuity".

The value will be  True if there is continuity and False if there is not.

Here are the rules :

```
1- The first row of a Name is always True as it is the start 
2-For a Name if the next row of Begin column has the same value with the previous row of End column, the value in Continuity column is True
3- In other cases it False
```

Here is my code :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'Eric', 1: 'Mattieu',2: 'Eric',3: 'Mattieu', 4: 'Mattieu',5: 'Eric',6: 'Mattieu'},
    'Begin': {0: '5/1/2016', 1: '7/1/2016',2: '10/1/2016',3: '20/1/2016', 4: '25/1/2016',5: '26/01/2016',6: '26/1/2016'},
                 'End': {0: '10/1/2016', 1: '18/1/2016',2: '26/1/2016',3: '24/1/2016', 4: '26/1/2016',5: '29/1/2016',6: '30/1/2016'},
                  })

df=df.sort_values(["Name"])
df
```

Here is the Ouput:

```
    Name    Begin       End
0   Eric    5/1/2016    10/1/2016
2   Eric    10/1/2016   26/1/2016
5   Eric    26/01/2016  29/1/2016
1   Mattieu 7/1/2016    18/1/2016
3   Mattieu 20/1/2016   24/1/2016
4   Mattieu 25/1/2016   26/1/2016
6   Mattieu 26/1/2016   30/1/2016
```

Here is the output I would like to have :

```
    Name    Begin       End         Continuity
0   Eric    2016/01/05  2016/01/10  True
2   Eric    2016/01/10  2016/01/26  True
5   Eric    2016/01/26  2016/01/29  True
1   Mattieu 2016/01/07  2016/01/18  True
3   Mattieu 2016/01/20  2016/01/24  False
4   Mattieu 2016/01/25  2016/01/26  False
6   Mattieu 2016/01/26  2016/01/30  True
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use:**

```
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'])
df['Begin'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Begin'])

s = df.groupby('Name')['End'].shift()
df['Continuity'] = df['Begin'].eq(s.fillna(df['Begin']))
```

**Details:**

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the dataframe on column `Name` then `shift` the column `End` to create a series `s`.

```
print(s)
0          NaT
2   2016-01-10
5   2016-01-26
1          NaT
3   2016-01-18
4   2016-01-24
6   2016-01-26
Name: End, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Use [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to compare the shifted column `End` with the `Begin` column and assign this result to `Continuity` column.

```
print(df)
      Name      Begin        End  Continuity
0     Eric 2016-05-01 2016-10-01        True
2     Eric 2016-10-01 2016-01-26        True
5     Eric 2016-01-26 2016-01-29        True
1  Mattieu 2016-07-01 2016-01-18        True
3  Mattieu 2016-01-20 2016-01-24       False
4  Mattieu 2016-01-25 2016-01-26       False
6  Mattieu 2016-01-26 2016-01-30        True
```

Comment: @hugo Added more explanation.

Comment: @hugo Lets discuss [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220026/ds10)